# Faster way of finding least-square solution for large matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, least-squares

I want to find the least-square solution of a matrix and I am using the numpy `linalg.lstsq` function;

```
weights = np.linalg.lstsq(semivariance, prediction, rcond=None)
```

The dimension for my variables are;

`semivariance` is a float of size 5030 x 5030

`prediction` is a 1D array of length 5030

The problem I have is it takes approximately 80sec to return the value of `weights` and I have to repeat the calculation of `weights` about 10000 times so the computational time is just elevated.

Is there a faster way/pythonic function to do this?

Comment: I doubt you're going to beat the [numpy implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1912) in speed in python. Especially since the heavy lifting is done by [C & Fortran](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src#L3161). It is quite possible that this is the best general implementation available. You're going to have to rethink your problem, which is beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: Since `semivariance` is a square matrix, it is faster to invert it and then use `dot` product: `weights = np.linalg.inv(semivariance).dot(prediction)`

Comment: Also, I just noticed your system is exactly determined, in which case is better to use `solve`: `weights = np.linalg.solve(semivariance, prediction)`. Both above methods assume `semivariance` is of full rank.

Comment: @user7436576, are you doing [kriging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging)?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, Yes. I am doing kriging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@[Brenlla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6091318/brenlla) appears to be right, even if you perform least squares by solving using the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse, it is significantly faster than `np.linalg.lstsq`:

```
import numpy as np
import time

semivariance=np.random.uniform(0,100,[5030,5030]).astype(np.float64)
prediction=np.random.uniform(0,100,[5030,1]).astype(np.float64)

start=time.time()
weights_lstsq = np.linalg.lstsq(semivariance, prediction, rcond=None)
print("Took: {}".format(time.time()-start))

>>> Took: 34.65818190574646

start=time.time()
weights_pseudo = np.linalg.solve(semivariance.T.dot(semivariance),semivariance.T.dot(prediction))
print("Took: {}".format(time.time()-start))

>>> Took: 2.0434153079986572

np.allclose(weights_lstsq[0],weights_pseudo)

>>> True
```

The above is not on your exact matrices but the concept on the samples likely transfers. `np.linalg.lstsq` performs an optimisation problem by minimizing `|| b - a x ||^2` to solve for `x` in `ax=b`. This is usually faster on extremely large matrices, hence why linear models are often solved using gradient decent in neural networks, but in this case the matrices just aren't large enough for the performance benefit.