# Improving computational speed during interpolation

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, scipy

**Problem**

The code performs geostatistic interpolation by applying kriging. For small data size, it works great. However, when the data is large, the computational time increases drastically.

**Constants**

`c1, c2, c3, c4` are constants

`matrx` is a dataset of size 6000 x 6000

**Variables**

`data` is a 6000 x 3 array

`gdata` is a 10000 x 2 array

**Code**

An extract of the code where I am having the problem is below:

```
prediction = []
for i, dummy_val in range(10000):
    semivariance = []
    for j in range(len(data[:, 2])):
        distance = np.sqrt((gdata[i, 0]-data[j, 0])**2 + (gdata[i, 1]-data[j, 1])**2)
        semivariance.append((c1 + c2*(1-np.exp(-(distance/c3)**c4))))
    semivariance.append(1)
    iweights = np.linalg.lstsq(matrx, semivariance, rcond=None)
    weights = iweights[:-3][0][:-1]
    prediction.append(np.sum(data[:, 2]*weights))
```

When I debug the code, I realize that the problem comes from the

```
iweights = np.linalg.lstsq(matrx, semivariance, rcond=None)
```

which runs very slow for the large `matrx` and `semivariance` array that I am using.

Is there a pythonic way to help improve the computational speed or a way I could rewrite the entire block of code to improve the speed?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288513/faster-way-of-finding-least-square-solution-for-large-matrix

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Some things seem similar (like the variable names). However, the context in this question is different, as Kriging implies the possibility of related repeating predictions, a context which leads to different possibilities (e.g., warm starts for gradient descent).

Comment: @AmiTavory, given the variable names, both look like questions about kriging.

Comment: If `matrx` is indeed the same for all `i`, you can e.g. compute its QR decomposition outside the loop, and then use that to solve the least-squares problem faster.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [MKL library binding](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-distribution-for-python-with-anaconda) to numpy? If not you can try it and check if it affect the performance of your code.

Also for the `prediction` and `semivariance` lists you are creating empty lists for both of them, then append a value for them on each iteration. As per my understanding, the number of iterations is fixed in your code, so will the code be faster if you created the lists with full size from the start to avoid dynamic creation of new list with every append? I don't know if the interpreter is smart enough to detect that the size of the list is fixed to create it and avoid the reallocation withou your help.