# numpy.linalg.lstsq too slow

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

I am trying to compare the performance of numpy.linalg.lstsq against solving the least-squares problem manually. I wrote the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

m,n = 400,10

A = np.random.rand(m,n)
b = np.random.rand(m)

t1 = timeit.timeit(lambda : np.linalg.inv(A.T@A) @ A.T @ b, number=100)
t2 = timeit.timeit(lambda : np.linalg.solve(A.T@A, A.T@b), number=100)
t3 = timeit.timeit(lambda : np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)[0], number=100)

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
```

To my surprise, the output is

```
0.0040054810015135445
0.002654149997397326
0.010454912000568584
```

`lstsq` is about 5 times slower. Why does this happen?

Comment: My *guess* is that `lstsq` is designed to handle a more general problem where `A` is not square or as 'well-formed'.  For example if I use `pinv(A.T@A)` in the first example, the time is a bit slower than `lstsq`.

Answer (score 2):

From [`lstsq`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) you may see it has a feature which the others doesn't:

> If there are multiple minimizing solutions, the one with the smallest 2-norm is returned.

In order to do so the problem needs to be examined and sometimes to be solved using the Pseudo Inverse while other methods can do other things like [QR Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition).

Comment: [np.linalg.solve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50330752/15893581) shown faster